# Are Extended-Length Paths safe to use?

Tags: windows, winapi, path, ntfs, unc

I just stumbled on [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247(VS.85).aspx) on MSDN that says a path can be 259 characters + NUL termination, but if you prefix it with "\\?\" WinAPI allows you to use the

> maximum total path length of 32,767 characters.

Eager to see it working I tried using that prefix from Explorer (On XP SP3) but it doesn't work at all (on any path). If you put `\\?\C:\Path\to\an\existing.file` on explorer's bar, it will give the "file not found" error.

So I'm confused. Can I code something for (non-ancient) Windows that makes full use of the mentioned path size on NTFS? Why Explorer doesn't use it?

Comment: Works in Windows 7 at least. In XP, maybe it works when calling API functions, but not when entering paths in the GUI of explorer.exe (which might allow for aribtrarily-length paths right away)?

Comment: Well, I've seen software (can't remember which) that created files in XP with paths bigger than 259, but explorer didn't let me use them correctly, not even delete them. To delete them I had to rename the parent folders to shorter names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a SET of API calls that are work with extened-paths and some that do not. The MSDN usually mentions this.

Not that if you just type that path into windows explorerunder xp this does not work, because the extened path syntax is just an escape sequence for the WIn32 API and not for windows explorer. Now, In Win7 this does work because many people expected this to work.

Also for long paths, it does help if you change the working directory or open up explorer with a sub-directory as a root.

Comment: What? "it does help if you change the working directory or open up explorer with a sub-directory as a root" You mean there is a `chroot` for Windows? Or you mean something else?

Comment: yes- there is a SetCurrentDirectory() And I might be wrong - but At some point in the past i *thought* that helped. At least if the app deals in relative paths, not absolute ones.

Comment: Choosen because it's been a while.

Comment: @CamiloMartin: `chroot` under Windows is `subst`. Note that it is not a security feature like it is supposed to be in Unix, just a convenience.

Comment: @Gabe nice to know! Might come handy if I have to work with a borked script that doesn't like spaces in paths.

Answer (score 1):

Before someone tells me to RTFM...

> Note that these examples are intended for use with the Windows API functions and do not all necessarily work with Windows shell applications such as Windows Explorer.
>   [...]
>   For file I/O, the "\\?\" prefix to a path string tells the Windows APIs to disable all string parsing and to send the string that follows it straight to the file system. For example, if the file system supports large paths and file names, you can exceed the MAX_PATH limits that are otherwise enforced by the Windows APIs.

On a secondary note, this makes me wonder about the possibilities of hiding files (or finding such files) from explorer by using illegal file names.

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking why all components in Windows do not support it, or are you asking whether it's legal to use these long paths?

You can definitely safely use them, but you may irritate someone who wants to use tools like Explorer to browse them.  We see paths like this all the time in the wild.  Sometimes people are pretty surprised when they can't use MY_FAVORITE_TOOL to delete it...

Comment: I'm actually thinking about developing a file browser that is less stupid than Explorer. I mean, NTFS offers a world of Unix-like possibilities that simply aren't *used* in XP.

Comment: edit: *"I'm thinking about developing a file browser"* = sometime between now and the end of time.