# How can I verify (in Visual C++ in MS VS 2013) that the string contents fits to fully qualified path or relative qualified path to folder?

Tags: c++, winapi, filepath

How can I verify (in Visual C++ in MS VS 2013) that the string contents fits to fully qualified path to folder or relative qualified path to folder? I have the following code:

```
 int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
 {
      // If command line contains a path to folder:
      if (argc == 2)
      {
       string folderPath = argv[1];

       // If this path doesn't exceed 248 characters:
       if (folderPath.size() <= MAX_PATH - 12)
       {
            /*
                    Here I must verify that the value of folderPath string variable
                    fits to fully qualified or relative qualified path to folder.
                */
           }
      }

      return 0;
 }
```

Is there any function in Visual C++ that can verify that the value of folderPath string variable fits to fully or relative qualified path to folder? My application is C++ console application without MFC support and I don't use BOOST. In my application I use multibyte character set but not unicode. I'll be very appreciative for the help.

Comment: Aren't you already doing that? Edit: Oh. I see. You want to fully qualify the input.

Comment: Do you know about extended length paths? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591840/are-extended-length-paths-safe-to-use

Comment: I not need to use the extended length path. I need to use 260 character path with 8.3 naming rules.

Comment: Are you asking how to verify that `folderPath` contains the name of a valid folder? Use [GetFileAttributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364944%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and check to see if the [FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg258117%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) flag is set.

Comment: No the OP is asking after conversion (most likely using a winapi function to convert) to a fully qualified or relative path will the path be valid?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773660%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: What do you mean by "fits to"? Fits into? I'm not seeing any buffers.