# How delete folders created by yeoman in Windows?

Tags: windows, directory, yeoman, windows-explorer

Following [this guide](http://yeoman.io/learning/index.html), after execute the command `yo webapp` a folder named *node_modules* is created. I want to delete that folder but I can't do it neither using command line or Windows file explorer because the path is too long. How I can delete this folder?

Error message at console:

> rmdir : The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully
>   qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the
>   directory name must be less than 248 characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify the path using [Extended Length Path syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591840/are-extended-length-paths-safe-to-use), e.g. `\\?\C:\Path\to\an\existing.file`.

Also, I successfully used [Total Commander](http://ghisler.com/) to delete a directory in a long path.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you be more specific? I tested with `rmdir \\Laptop\C:\Users\USERNAME\tmp\my-yo-project /s` and it did not work.

Comment: What about `rmdir \\?\C:\Users\USERNAME\tmp\my-yo-project /s`

Comment: That command produce another error, do you test that command? or you re just guessing?

Comment: It works for me to delete `d:\temp\todelete` I typed `rmdir \\?\d:\temp\todelete` and it worked.  This is on Win 7 x64.

Comment: Pls, note that I'm not asking for a command to delete a normal folder, I'm asking for a command (or whatever) to delete a folder that can't be deleted using windows explorer because the path is too long and the normal windows command gave the error that I had put in my original question. Your command worked because you don't used the `/s` and because you were not trying to delete a super deep directory tree.

Comment: I see what you mean.  I was thrown off by your shorter example starting with `\\Laptop` in your comment .  [This article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591840/are-extended-length-paths-safe-to-use) implies you can at least get Explorer to show the long path, but I could not get it to work.  [Total Commander](http://www.ghisler.com/) is a tool I used just now to delete the long path I had created to experiment with your case, and you may find it helpful.

Comment: Total Commander worked. Thanks, pls edit your answer to spot easily the solution to others users. Thanks again.

Comment: I tried rmdir \\?\c:\mydir and all I get are errors saying the path is too long

Answer (score 0):

You can use [rimraf](https://github.com/isaacs/rimraf) which is the [unix command](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rm_(Unix)) `rm -rf` for node.:

```
$ rimraf <name of dir to delete>
```

You can install rimraf using npm:

```
$ npm install -g rimraf
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to a newish [open-source project](https://github.com/Microsoft/winfile) released by Microsoft, you can easily delete paths that are too long  using [WinFile](https://github.com/Microsoft/winfile) (which was introduced in WinXP). 
Sometimes you have to go "Back to the Future". This can delete paths too long on Microsoft networks share as well.

[image]

WinFile (compiled for Win10) available here https://github.com/Microsoft/winfile

To find many paths that are too long and automate a fix, I recommend [Path Too Long Auto Fixer](https://pathtoolongautofixer.blogspot.com/) - a free demo is available.